# website files saved in browse's cache prevent changes from being displayed

Tags: css, ftp, web-publishing

This is probably a dumb question, but I'm worried :

- I have published a website on a server, then made some changes to a css file.
- As the css file was already cached by my browser, it didn't display the changes.
- deleting the cash allowed to display the changes.

Now my worry is that if some users have previously been to the website, and it is cached by their browser, if I make a change they wouldn't be able to see it.

How do you guys prevent this ? Do you just change the file names ?

Sorry for my noobness,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solutions floating around the web, but as far as I can tell they all boil down to changing the CSS filenames whenever their content changes. That way you steer clear of user caches and server caches serving old content.

Variants:

- Instead of changing the name of the file itself, create a symbolic link with a new name to the old file whenever content changes.
- Instead of changing the name of the file, change the way it is referenced by the page. Replacing `myfile.css?v=1` by `myfile.css?v=2` circumvents people's caches.
- Write code that automatically changes the name or the link name or the way the file is referenced
- Use a framework that does one of the above.

And: remember that the same problem applies to any content that might be cached, like JS files.